# HTML range slider show JSON dependant on date

Tags: javascript, json, slider, range

I have a JSON file containing:

```
{"mapping": [
    [
        "london",
        "51.18452",
        "-0.150839",
        "2016-04-19"
    ],
    [
        "london",
        "52.6127",
        "-2.02296",
        "2016-04-21"
    ],
    [
        "london",
        "53.334",
        "-6.2761",
        "2016-04-15"
    ]
}
```

Within my HTML I wish to have a range slider like this:

```
[]-----------------
oldest       recent
```

In this scenario, the oldest JSON data should be shown, so

```
    "london",
    "53.334",
    "-6.2761",
    "2016-04-15"
```

And as the user slowly moves the range slider closer to the right end, more recent data should be shown..

```
----------------[]-
oldest       recent
```

displaying..

```
    "london",
    "52.6127",
    "-2.02296",
    "2016-04-21"
```

I have many other values within the JSON file, I just used these three examples to show the format of the file. I am creating a heat map and whilst the slider moves along, the heat map should change to generate different points. Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Turning the arrays into objects is optional, but it is much easier to reference properties like that, also it allowed us to convert the date string into a date object which has a number value to compare with.

```
const objectMapping = data.mapping.map(element => ({city:element[0], latitude:element[1], longitude:element[2], date:new Date(element[3])}));
```

Now that you have objects rather than an array, you can just say `Array.sort` on the date object where if `b` is higher than `a`, then `b` will come before `a` in the list

```
const sortedMapping = objectMapping.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
```

Then `sortedMapping[0]` = oldest date